# QPainter, рисование текста без заливки

Tags: c++, qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как написать такой текст с помощью `QPainter`, чтобы текст изнутри был прозрачным?

Comment: QFont имеет кучу опций, наверняка там найдётся и та, что требуется Вам.

Comment: @vegorov, а вот и нет, `QFont` не умеет в обводку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сам `QPainter` не поддерживает непосредственное рисование контура текста. Однако вы можете создать этот контур отдельно, с помощью `QPainterPath::addText()`.

То есть для получения текста без заливки надо:

1. Векторизовать его:

   ```
   QPainterPath outline_text;
   outline_text.addText(положение, шрифт, текст);
   ```
2. И затем отрисовать:

   ```
   QPainter painter(this);
   painter.strokePath(outline_text, перо);
   ```

Вот минимальный демонстрационный пример:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QFont>
#include <QPalette>
#include <QPen>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPainterPath>
#include <QWidget>

/* ************* */

class Canvas : public QWidget {
public:
    Canvas();

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
    QPainterPath outline_text;
    QPen outline_pen;
    QRect outline_bounds;
};

/* ************* */

Canvas::Canvas()
    : outline_pen(Qt::lightGray, 2)
{
    // "Запекаем" контур надписи в экземпляр QPainterPath. И да, текст мы размещаем
    // в начале координат, так как всё равно потом будем динамически перемещать его
    // в центр окна
    QFont outline_font(QLatin1String("serif"), 64);
    outline_text.addText(QPoint(), outline_font, QLatin1String("Hello, World"));

    // Сохраняем описывающий прямоугольник для дальнейшего центрирования надписи
    outline_bounds = outline_text.controlPointRect().toRect();

    // Устанавливаем белый цвет фона
    QPalette pal(palette());
    pal.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::white);
    setPalette(pal);
}

void Canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    // Перемещаем надпись в центр окна
    const QPoint outline_center = outline_bounds.center();
    const QPoint canvas_center = rect().center();
    painter.translate(canvas_center - outline_center);

    // Рисуем контур
    painter.strokePath(outline_text, outline_pen);

    event->accept();
}

/* ************* */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Canvas canvas;
    canvas.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

И результат его работы:

[image: Экранный снимок]

Comment: Спасибо помогло